# Python Mysql Request with variables

Tags: python, mysql

I have used python for a long time but I have trouble with a particular string-variable manipulation case

I want to do something like this:

```
##################################

#sample
MYROW= 'ID_project'

result=curs.execute("""select %s FROM shotmanager_projects""",(MYROW))

#result=curs.execute("""select %s FROM shotmanager_projects""",('ID_sample')) 
# don t work too

###################################
```

And it doesnt work at all!

Why isn't `% var` not accepted in this case?

Answer (score 3):

`(x)` is not a tuple with one element, it is a normal value. `(x,)` is a tuple with one element.

Answer (score 0):

result = curs.execute("select %s FROM shotmanager_projects", (MYROW,))

Comment: Don't Work:    MYROW = 'title' result=curs.execute("""select %s FROM shotmanager_projects""",(MYROW)) 'code'    return: (('title'),),(('title'),),(('title'),),(('title'),)